# Off-the-shelf synthetiser solution for MIDI piano

Tags: midi

I am thinking about using one of my Raspberry PIs to turn USB midi keyboard into a standalone piano.

Is there a piece of software I can use? Ideally a single-purpose image akin to the RaspBMC etc.

Ideally, it would also allow selection of instruments via graphical UI connected via the HDMI port.

Comment: you can try something like [vmpk](http://vmpk.sourceforge.net) i am not sure if this works on a pi but it is open source. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a pre-built distribution or image, but there is a blog post here by someone who set up a similar thing, and how they did it:
http://jacquespi.blogspot.de/2013/07/synthesizer.html